# Dragging onto the exit of the viewcontroller not working

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, segue

I have looked for this problem everywhere.
I know how the unwind scene works. I have implemented the following code in the A VC

```
-(IBAction)returned:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
try.text = @"Returned from Scene 1";
}
```

But when I go to my B VC(Which is the VC I want to go back to A VC from) and ctrl drag a button onto the exit at the bottom it will not allow me to. And no function pops up in the exits option. Anyone else had this issue or can help?

Comment: Did you add the public declaration to A's .h? Also what's the type of segue from A to B?

Comment: B is a subclass of A? Should that do it?

Comment: No. You should have two scenes on your storyboard, one whose custom class is A, the other's whose is B. You should then have push or modal segue from A to B. And if A's unwind action us defined in A's .h, When you drag from a control on B to B's exit outlet, you should see your unwind segue listed there.

Comment: This is what I have defined in A's .h
      `- (IBAction)returned:(id)sender;`

Comment: It should match the method: `-(IBAction)returned:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;` (personally, I'm not crazy about that name ... I'd call it `unwindToA` or something like that; You want something that is descriptive when using IB (imagine that you had a whole series of scenes that preceded B ... you'd like it to be obvious that you're going to A); I also like to follow the `verbNoun` format when it works.)

Comment: That did the trick Rob. Thanks very much. Sorry if the question was very basic

Comment: You actually don't need to declare that method in the .h file at all, but I think having it there with the wrong signature was your problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To set up an unwind segue, you should

1. Set up your two scenes with the standard modal or push segue between them:

   [image]
2. Define the custom classes for those two scenes to be your respective view controllers.
3. Implement the action in the .m for view controller A:

   ```
   - (IBAction)unwindToA:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
   {
       //returning to A
   }
   ```
4. Then you can create a segue in B by <kbd>control</kbd>-dragging (or right-click-dragging) from some control down to the exit outlet in the bar below scene `B`:

   [image]
5. And if everything above is configured correctly, you will now see your unwind segue listed in a popover:

   [image]

Comment: You don't actually need the declaration in the .h, Xcode still finds it as long as you implement a method with the correct signature.

Comment: @rdelmar Thanks. Removed unnecessary .h  declaration from my answer.

Answer (score 4):

To make Exit outlet active, add this code to viewController. Now you should be able to ctrl-drag to exit outlet.
It is actually quite odd, that there should be empty method to make it work.

```
swift
@IBAction func unwindSegue(unwindSegue:UIStoryboardSegue) 

objC
- (IBAction)unwindSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)sender;
```

Comment: I find that for beginners, they tend to forget the `@IBAction` keyword for the Interface Builder to discover the unwind function.

Answer (score 1):

I also had a problem with this even though everything was set up correctly. Eventually I tried closing the project and reopening it and that did the trick. Must have been some bug in Xcode.

This doesn't seem to have been the cause of your problem but I thought I'd add the answer in case someone else has the same problem.

Comment: Hey the same is happening to me! Just randomly now I have no more "Exit" popups. But I closed and reopened Xcode and it still doesn't work! Arghhh

Comment: Fixed it by removed the Derived data and restarting Xcode.

Comment: Facing the same issue, there are no "Exit" popups even restarting does not seems to work for me. Is there any other way to fix this?

Comment: Does your method in the destination view controller conform to the format `- (IBAction)unwindMethodName:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue`?

Answer (score 0):

@LoPoBo, @hozefam, & @Van Du Tran

If closing down isn't working, perhaps you were dragging in the wrong manner. Instead of clicking on the `Bar Button Item` and dragging from `Action Segue` to the `exit` try just right click -> hold & drag to `exit segue`. This was messing with me for a good 20min before I figured it out. Hope this helps someone else too. Using xcode 6.1